# Spring Boot Web with Thymeleaf: HTML template can't find the given JS file

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I just set up a very basic Spring Boot Web Application with Thymeleaf, but I can't access my external JS file from the corresponding HTML file of my template and can't figure out why.

My resource folder structure is as follows:

- static/

  - index.html
  - css/

    - graph.css
  - js/

    - createGraph.js
- templates/

  - visualizeGraph.html

Within my `visualizeGraph.html` I try to call the `createGraph.js` using following snippet within the `<body>` element:

```
    <script th:src="@{/js/createGraph.js}" type="text/javascript" >
    </script>
```

In the `<head>` element of `visualizeGraph.html`, I added my stylesheet using following snippet:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
          href="/css/graph.css" th:href="@{/css/graph.css}" />
```

My Spring Boot Web Container runs on Port `:8082`, so I access my webapplication from `localhost:8082` and access the visualizeGraph template from `localhost:8082/visualizeGraph`

When I check the Developer Console (F12), it throws a 404 for the `createGraph.js` file, but not for the `graph.css` file -> it can find the css successfully.

I can even access the css through `localhost:8082/css/graph.css` but CAN'T access the js-file using `localhost:8082/js/createGraph.js` (throws a 404 - as expected)

I can't figure, what's the cause for this phenomenon as my application.properties also has no additional parameters for modifying the resource source folder etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was VERY weird. I found the solution, but I am not sure, whether it's IntelliJ, which was responsible for this problem or something else.

What I did was to edit my `<script>` element in my HTML file to the following:

```
<script src="/js/createGraph.js" type="text/javascript" >
</script>
```

and my intention was solely to try out, whether it would change anything. Somehow, IntelliJ told me, that it was not able to find the path (neither the js folder, nor the `createGraph.js` file within it) so what it suggested was to create the folder and the file (so I did, using ALT+Enter). What I did afterwards is to just copy the content of my old `createGraph.js` to the new file and to delete the (very strangely the same named) old folder and file and voila, everything works as expected... Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your JS files present in resources/static folder like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

No need to give the forward slash before the js folder.

below I am attaching screenshot for my code:
[image]

Here, I was having images folder inside the static folder so we can directly call that folder.

If you have any further doubts please feel free to visit my github [amisham96](https://github.com/amisham96/Springboot_H2-database_CRUD)

Comment: Hi kode fyi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I also tried this and this didn't work out. Check out my own answer at the bottom for the solution to my problem.